# Printing an RDLC file in ASP.NET MVC 3 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file from what the user entered. It is entered in a database file fine; however it is not been printed on the pdf file. When I try to debug it shows that it does have data. I'm not sure if it is because of the stored procedure that pulls the data. Is there a possibility that someone can assist me with this question; the issue is this line DataSet ds = dbdata.GetReceipt(getIssue.requisitionNumber); but rather than using a stored procedure; i would like to know how else I can show the data entered on the pdf file.  Whenever I try to execute the pdf file this is what I get [image]

```
<input type="button" id="ReceiptPrint" value="Print/Issue" name="Print/Issue" class="btn btn-default col-md-4" />

 $m(document).ready(function () {
            $m('#ReceiptPrint').click(function () {
                window.open("ReceiptPrint");
            });
        });

 public DataSet GetReceipt(string req_num)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "issue_sp_getreceipt";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@reqnum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = req_num;
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Receipt");

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }


            return ds;
        }


    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[issue_sp_getreceipt] 

    @reqnum varchar (16)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT empiitem.*, b.ACTNUMBR_1+ '-' +b.ACTNUMBR_2 + '/' + b.ACTDESCR [Expense_Account], c.ACTNUMBR_1+ '-' +c.ACTNUMBR_2 + '/' + c.ACTDESCR [Inventory_Account], 
                empiitem.CURRCOST*quantity [extended_Cost]
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT empdata.*, b.ITEMDESC  from
            (   
                Select *
                from 
                (Select Right(a.doc_num,12) [receipt_num], a.requisition_num, a.department, ab.expense_acc, a.inventory_acc_indx, a.issuer_id, ab.itemnum, ab.quantity, a.trans_date,
                        b.emp_firstname as [deptrepfname], b.emp_lastname [deptreplname], c.emp_firstname [Issuerfname],c.emp_lastname [Issurelname], ab.cost [CURRCOST], ab.uofm 
                    from [dbo].Issue a Inner Join dbo.IssueItem ab
                    on a.doc_num= ab.doc_num Left Outer Join [dbo].[Employee] b
                             on cast(a.dept_rep_id as int) = b.employee_id
                             Left join Employee c
                             on cast(a.issuer_id as int)= c.employee_id
                             where doc_type = 'Issue'
                ) as emp
            ) empdata 
            Inner Join [TWCL].[dbo].[IV00101] b
                on empdata.itemnum = b.ITEMNMBR
        ) empiitem 
        Inner Join [TWCL].[dbo].[GL00100] b
            on empiitem.expense_acc = b.ACTINDX
        Inner Join [TWCL].[dbo].[GL00100] c 
            on empiitem.inventory_acc_indx = c.ACTINDX
    WHERE requisition_num  = @reqnum



END 


public ActionResult ReceiptPrint(Issue issue)
    {
        IssueDAO dbdata = new IssueDAO();
        dbdata.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        getIssue.transactionDate = DateTime.Now; //Sets the transaction date to current date
        getIssue.status = -1;
        Item item = new Item();
        try
        {
            dbdata.createIssue(getIssue, item);//Creates the issue in the database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to complete the Issue. Please see Log file for more Information";
            return View("IssueItem", getIssue);

        }


        DataSet ds = dbdata.GetReceipt(getIssue.requisitionNumber);
        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"Reports\Reciept.rdlc";
        localreport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Receipt_Data", ds.Tables[0]));
        localreport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Req_num", getIssue.requisitionNumber));
        string reporttype = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>              
                 <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>              
                 <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>              
                 <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>          
                 <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>          
                 <MarginLeft>0.45in</MarginLeft>            
                 <MarginRight>0.45in</MarginRight>       
                 <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;
        renderedBytes = localreport.Render(
         reporttype, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension,
         out streams, out warnings);


        var doc = new Document();
        var reader = new PdfReader(renderedBytes);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt" +
             Convert.ToString(Session["CurrentUserName"]) + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
            string Printer = "Xerox Phaser 3635MFP PCL6";
            // This is the script for automatically printing the pdf in acrobat viewer
            stamper.JavaScript = "var pp = getPrintParams();pp.interactive =pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic; pp.printerName = " +
                           Printer + ";print(pp);\r";
            stamper.Close();
        }
        reader.Close();
        FileStream fss = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fss.Length];
        fss.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fss.Length));
        fss.Close();
        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Receipt.pdf"));

        //Here we returns the file result for view(PDF)
        //ModelState.Clear();
        //Session.Clear(); //Clears the session variable for reuse 
        return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Did You try this link [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/569335/Automatically-Printing-an-RDLC-file-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: Yes I did..but i think found out what the problem is. Not the part about the pdf but the line that draws the actual data here DataSet ds = dbdata.GetReceipt(getIssue.requisitionNumber); But I would like besides using a stored procedure how else to write the getreceipt function